# "cannot access local variable 'a' where it is not associated with a value", but the value is defined

Tags: python

I don't know why when `a` is located in `def test()` it can not be found and gives the error

> UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'a' where it is not associated with a value

#### Code

```py
import keyboard
import time

a = 0

def test():
    a+= 1
    print("The number is now ", a)
    time.sleep(1)

while keyboard.is_pressed('i') == False:

    test()
```

I tried setting `a` as `global a` or using a `nonlocal` modifier on it inside the `def`, but it doesn't seem to work. Is there a way I can get it to recognize `a` and run properly?

Answer (score 32):

Python variables are scope based. This means one cannot access a value declared inside a function. But you can access a variable declared outside a function.

This would fail:

```
def func():
    a = 1

func()
print(a)
```

This would print `1`:

```
def func():
    print(a)

a = 1
func()
```

Notice you can access it. You'll fail if you want to update it.

This would fail too:

```
def func():
    a = a + 1
    print(a)

a = 1
func()
```

You need to tell the interpreter to find variable `a` in the global scope.

```
def func():
    global a
    a = a + 1
    print(a)

a = 1
func()
```

Warning: It's not a good practice to use `global` variables. So better make sure the function is getting the value.

```
def func(a):
    a = a + 1
    print(a)

a = 1
func(a)
```

Answer (score 6):

To access a global variable within a function you must specify it with global. Otherwise, the variable inside the function is a local variable that only has utility inside that function. That's why you get the error: "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'a' referenced before assignment". Inside the function you haven't defined the variable 'a' yet, either local or global.

```
import keyboard
import time

a = 0

def test():
    global a
    a+= 1
    print("The number is now ", a)
    time.sleep(1)

while keyboard.is_pressed('i') == False:
    
    test()
```

Comment: One CAN ACCESS a global variable from a function, but CANNOT UPDATE the value.

Comment: @MSH Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: I do not know exactly why. It's a design choice. You need to do a research to understand why. Maybe it helps with memory management/garbage collection.

Comment: @MSH: that's wrong, you **can** modify a global variable inside a function.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass a to the function test. Python thinks as the `a` in the function as a local variable.
This will work:

```
import keyboard
import time
a = 0
def test(a=a):
    a+= 1
    print("The number is now ", a)
    time.sleep(1)
while keyboard.is_pressed('i') == False:
    test()
```