# How do I run a function from another script in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Lets say **FileA** and **FileB** are my two files that do stuff. **FileA** has as an import **FileB**
has some variables and functions. The Function I want to call in **FileA** from **FileB** is **X** which is using some other variables and functions of **FileB**. When I try to run the program I get an error saying that "Cannot acces local variable if it's not defined". Now I imagine that it would get all the stuff I declared in **FileB** but it doesn't. How can I go about this without making my program have a ton of references? Can't I just run my function from **FileA** while using **FileB** contents? Note that I am a beginner and it might be a stupid question! And also I will compile the files togheter at the end if it's of any help.

EDIT: If I declare Pas inside my function it does work! But I have too many things to define inside it. Why won't it pick up the context from **FileB** ?

Example in Code:
**FileA**

```
import FileB as fb

print(fb.X())
```

**FileB**

```
import random
global Pas
p = "ok"
u = [some randomly generated stuff]

def RandomLetterGen:
   some code

Pas = ""
def X():
 Pas += RandomLetterGen()
 return Pas
```

This is an easy to understand example but my code does much more to get to the result of the X function in **FileB**

I tried looking it up online but no luck.

Comment: Post the exact traceback instead of describing it. And post real (minimal) code that you've tested - the code you've shown has syntax errors and other issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to initialize **Pas** inside the **X()** function?

```
def X():
 Pas = ""
 Pas += RandomLetterGen()
 return Pas
```

Comment: It does work but I have already defined all of my variables global

Comment: To answer your edit @Teroro, this works because the declaration of Pas is now in scope of the function.

Comment: If I imported all the fileB can't I make it to automaticly search in **FileB** for these ?

Comment: you need to use the **global** keyword if you want to reassign the global variable within a function. If you just need to read or access the value of the global variable from within your function, then you don’t need the **global** keyword

Answer (score 0):

The following FileB works OK for me

```
import random
p = "ok"
u = "[1, 2, 3]"

def X():
 return p + u
```

Maybe it's something to do with your u variable rather than the 2 files. Adding a list to a string will also cause a problem.

Comment: I edited it so it looks a bit better

Comment: Add 'global Pas' at start of X. That should work.

Comment: It didn't work. "cannot access local variable 'Password' where it is not associated with a value"

Answer (score 0):

You have an Error at a different place since the acces to local variables works in Python. This example will work:

**File A:**

```
import FileB as fb
print(fb.getP())
```

**File B:**

```
p = "ok"

def getP():
 return p
```

---

My guess is that your Error is in calculating value

```
u = [some randomly generated stuff]
```

I guess here you try to access a local variable in a different function. Have a look here for solutions:
["cannot access local variable 'a' where it is not associated with a value", but the value is defined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74412503/21250873)

Comment: I tried putting the value as global

Comment: Have a look at the variables you use in each function. Somewhere you try to access a local variabl wich is only defined in another function. Make this variable global.

Comment: I made all my variables global including Pas and it doesn't work

Comment: can you show us what you have written in RandomLetterGen()?

Comment: I made an Edit and I am pretty sure it isn't because RandomLetterGen

Comment: At a different answer you commented your Error-Massage being "cannot access local variable 'Password' where it is not associated with a value".

Can you show us how "Password" is defined?